# Sanitize Form Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sanitization

I'm just learning the basics of PHP and scripting after building sites with HTML/CSS. I'm trying to make a simple form that submits to a database, just to gather email address and names. Below is the basic is the code I'm using. I've got a few tweaks in it, but nothing major. I know I need to sanitize this data and I've read dozens of post, articles etc on how to do this I just don't see how to add the escape_string or PHP functions to this. I thought I did and I've tried it dozens of ways, but when I test it seems like they don't make any difference. I know its just my noobie ignorance that's doing this, but I'm kind of pulling my hair put, so any help would be great.

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
    if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

    mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

@rwhite35 is this what the end result should look like?

```
<?php
// sanitize a string in prep for passing a single argument to system() (or similar)
function sanitize_system_string($string, $min='', $max='')
{
  $pattern = '/(;|\||`|>|<|&|^|"|'."\n|\r|'".'|{|}|[|]|\)|\()/i'; 
  // no piping, passing possible environment variables ($),
  // seperate commands, nested execution, file redirection, 
  // background processing, special commands (backspace, etc.), quotes
  // newlines, or some other special characters
 $string = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
 //make sure this is only interpreted as ONE argument
 $string = '"'.preg_replace('/\$/', '\\\$', $string).'"'; 
 $len = strlen($string);
  if((($min != '') && ($len < $min)) || (($max != '') && ($len > $max)))
    return FALSE;
    return $string;
  }

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("form-try", $con);

$firstname = sanitize_system_string($_POST['firstname'],2,44);
$lastname = sanitize_system_string($_POST['lastname'],2,44);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: If you are at the bricks of learning PHP, start by using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database uses

Comment: Look into prepared statements as well, using prepared statements will decrease the chance of SQL injection attacks on your scripts/code.

Answer (score 5):

You're code is prone to **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST[firstname]);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST[lastname]);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST[age]);

    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

this will allow you to insert records with single quotes.

Comment: If you want to learn and to know what you are doing, don't use PDO. Use the mysql and mysqli functions to learn what's playing inside those hermetic objects. Then when you start with real-life applications, use  PDO.

Comment: you mean `mysql_*`? it's already depreciated according to the manual.

Comment: Let me see if I'm understand this correctly I would use the PDO example above in place of this part of what I'm using?<code>'$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";</code>

Comment: the values of the insert should be parameterized. the PDO will automatically sanitize the values for you.

Comment: Okay I obvious have a lot to learn about this. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the "values of input should be parameterized", but I appreciate your trying to help and at least pointing me in a new direction to learn from.

Comment: @user1660445 is should be `INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES (?,?,?)`

Comment: @John Woo So it should look like this then?  `<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost:8888","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("form-try", $con);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST[firstname]);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST[lastname]);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST[age]);

    $stmt->execute();

mysql_close($con);


?>`
That doesn't seem to be submitting the info to my database. I know its my ignorance though.

Comment: @user1660445 because you didn't create an active connection for your `pdo`. before preparing your insert add this code, `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);`

Answer (score 0):

I think John Woo is referring to you passing $_POST[firstname] directly in to your INSERT statement.  Thats dangerous.  Here is simple function I use to scrub the input, then I'll use mysqli for the query.  This is a "belt and suspenders" approach.

```
// sanitize a string in prep for passing a single argument to system() (or similar)
function sanitize_system_string($string, $min='', $max='')
{
  $pattern = '/(;|\||`|>|<|&|^|"|'."\n|\r|'".'|{|}|[|]|\)|\()/i'; 
  // no piping, passing possible environment variables ($),
  // seperate commands, nested execution, file redirection, 
  // background processing, special commands (backspace, etc.), quotes
  // newlines, or some other special characters
 $string = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
 //make sure this is only interpreted as ONE argument
 $string = '"'.preg_replace('/\$/', '\\\$', $string).'"'; 
 $len = strlen($string);
  if((($min != '') && ($len < $min)) || (($max != '') && ($len > $max)))
    return FALSE;
    return $string;
  }
```

Then later in your code that is processing the form data...

```
$firstname = sanitize_system_string($_POST['firstname'],2,44);
$lastname = sanitize_system_string($_POST['lastname'],2,44);
```

This process will instantiate the variable $firstname and $lastname with the result of function sanitize_system_string; which is removing characters like "{,<,&,`,;" in your $_POST variable. Those could be read by the mysql engine as commands. Additionally it sets a minimum and maximum numbers of characters.  The input has to be a min of 2 characters and no more than 44.
Good luck

Comment: Please see above :) It still submits the info to the db, but I'm not sure I'm causing you function run. I'm not really sure how to test it.

Comment: You might have tried this already, but in your form field, enter 'string then {<&`; more text'  Then if your input name was name="someText", you would then call the function with $testVar = sanitize_system_string($_POST['someText'],2,44); echo $testVar; The output should be "sting then more text".  Which would omit the special characters.